# KDE customise session lock dialog

Tags: kde

I have Kubuntu/KDE4.

On some Linuxes, when the session is locked, the unlocking dialog shows a clock, or perhaps some other widgets.

Not mine, it's just a password entry with Unlock/Cancel/Switch User buttons.

Where can I change what this dialog contains?

Comment: I had this the last time I was a kde user. Now that you ask, I can't seem to find out how to activate it. Perhaps it has disappeared in some kde version? (I'm on Gentoo)

Comment: @richard, Kubuntu, as I said at the top.

Comment: What version are you on, it may make a difference to the answer. And what display-manager.